# Determine an equation of a sphere which passes through vertices of a pyramid

Tags: vectors

Here are the givens:
Triangular pyramid with coordinates of (0,0,0) origin A(12,0,0) B(0,6,0) and C(0,0,4).
Determine the equation of a sphere that passes through the vertices of the pyramid OABC.

Part 2:
Then once I have the equation of this sphere, how do i show that the center of the sphere DOES NOT lie inside of the pyramid? I don't know the method with checking if its on the same side of all planes or whatnot, I'm still in highschool, so I need the most simple mathematical way to show that. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The center of the sphere (cyan) is the red ball with center (6,3,2) the sphere has radius 7 .  Its equation is:

$$(x - 6)^2 + (y - 3)^2 + (z-2)^2 = 49$$

The coordinate planes are in grey , $ x=0$, $y=0$ , and $z=0$ , plus one more plane ( shown in pink) it has equation: $ z = -x/3 - 2y/3 + 4 $
. The point at (0,0,0) can't be seen in the picture (which is great because we know it is the origin of the coordinate system and the pink plane prevents us from viewing it.)

So ,what is a natural way to show  that (0,0,0) and (6,3,2) are separated from each other by the plane $ z = -x/3 - 2y/3 + 4 $  ?

Comment: how did you determine the equation of the sphere? :)

Comment: look at this question and answer carefully: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98530/equation-of-a-sphere-as-the-determinant-of-its-variables-and-sampled-points I think the answer is particularly good.

Comment: Let me make a confession, I've wanted to use this forumla:  $$\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}
x^2+y^2+z^2 & x & y&z&1\\
x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2 & x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & 1\\
x_2^2 + y_2^2 + z_2^2 & x_2 & y_2 & z_2 & 1\\
x_3^2 + y_3^2 + z_3^2 & x_3 & y_3 & z_3 & 1\\
x_4^2 + y_4^2 + z_4^2 & x_4 & y_4 & z_4 & 1\\
\end{array}\right| = 0$$ since I was a high school student, and now I have!

Comment: i Don't really understand the formula though ;/

Comment: Anyway, i think i solved it similarly, but just using simultaneous equations, without all those brackets.

Comment: I don't know sorry. Can you help me with part 2 and proving it? Is the plane x + 2y + 3z = 4 ? Because that is the way I'm used to seeing equations of planes

Comment: multiplying through by 3  gives   $ 3z = -x -2y + 12$  and rearranging  terms $  x + 2y + 3z  =  12 $  . You can verify that when y = z = 0 then x = 12, when x=z=0 then y = 6 and when x=y=0 then z = 4 , so the intersection with the axes occur at (12,0,0) , (0,6,0) , (0,0,4) which are points A, B, and C . The idea I hhad was to extent a line from (0,0,0) to (6,3,2) by using (6t , 3t, 2t) and substituting these quantities into the equation for the plane showing that was a point of intersection, in other words the line that has been constructed passes through the plane,so try to find the point.

Comment: I got t=2/3 so point on the plane and line would be (4,2,4/3).

Comment: I thought and thought and finally figured it out. thanks man, you're such a genius. In other places i was getting complicated ways to do this with planes etc. and seeing distances, but lines are just so much nicer :P kudos